# use mtail and prometheus: what's the correct way to calculate average of a metric

Tags: logging, prometheus

Say we'd like to monitor the response in nginx logs, the example in mtail's code shows something like this:

```
/$/ {
 strptime($timestamp, "02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700") # for tests

 apache_http_requests_total[$request_method][$http_version][$status_code]++
 $response_size > 0 {
  apache_http_bytes_total[$request_method][$http_version][$status_code] += $response_size
  apache_http_response_size[$remote_host][$request_method][$request_uri][$status_code][$user_agent] += $response_size
 }
 apache_http_response_time[$remote_host][$request_method][$request_uri][$status_code][$user_agent] = $response_time
```

}

but when multiple lines are parsed by mtail, doesn't it only get the response_time in the last line?

if we want to have an average_response_time in prometheus, should we collect total_response_time and use `rate()` function in prometheus?

Answer (score 0):

> but when multiple lines are parsed by mtail, doesn't it only get the response_time in the last line?

If `apache_http_response_time` is a gauge, yes. If it's a histogram, it will collect the total number of events and total latency (allowing you to compute the mean / average over any time period using `rate()`), plus counts per bucket, allowing you to estimate percentiles (including the median). mtail [appears to support](http://google.github.io/mtail/Programming-Guide.html#histograms) histograms as first class citizens.

> if we want to have an average_response_time in prometheus, should we collect total_response_time and use `rate()` function in prometheus?

That would give you the ratio (possibly above 1) of time spent serving requests. E.g. if over the past 10 seconds you got 5 requests that each took 1 second, you'd get a rate of `0.5`. OTOH, if there were 2 requests, each taking 10 seconds, you'd get a rate of `2`.